# NSGliff for Swift Dictionary Key - Using uintptr_t?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I need to use an NSGlyph as the key in a Swift dictionary

```
var glyph:NSGlyph //set to a glyph
var glyphDict:[NSGlyph:CGPath] //Will contain a cache of glyphs previously converted to paths
var path = glyphDict[glyph]
```

but I get:

> error: '[NSGlyph : CGPath]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

So I guess Apple hasn't defined a subscript for NSGlyph?

I've found this code from Apple's VectorTextLayer Sample Code that successfully uses a CGGlyph as a key in a CFDictionary.  How can I adapt this to work in a Swift dictionary?

```
    CGPathRef path = (CGPathRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(glyphDict, (const void *)(uintptr_t)glyph);
```

I understand that code is wrapping the CGGlyph into a uintptr_t.  How could I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've copied different code in your question. That error happens when the variable you're using as dictionary is an optional, so declared as:

```
var glyphDict:[NSGlyph:CGPath]?
```

To solve the issue, you can read from the dictionary using optional chaining:

```
var path = glyphDict?[glyph]
```

Note that `path` is an optional itself.

Comment: Yeah, code wasn't copied right.  Looks like I've got more to learn about optionals.  Thanks!